# HAProxy can't talk to database server -- Connection reset by peer

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to replace an old haproxy server with a new one. On the old server, for HA-Proxy version 1.5.14, I have the following config (all IP address are fake):

```
listen dbserver 1.2.3.1:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    maxconn 50
    timeout server 300s
    timeout client 300s
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 info
    balance roundrobin
    option  httpchk
    server db1 1.2.3.2:3306 check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 3 backup
    server db2 1.2.3.3:3306 check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 3
```

This works as expected. On the new server, for HA-Proxy version 2.2.9-2+deb11u5, I'm trying:

```
listen dbserver 
    bind 1.2.3.4:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    maxconn 50
    timeout server 300s
    timeout client 300s
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 info
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    server db1 1.2.3.2:3306 check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 3 backup
    server db2 1.2.3.3:3306 check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 3
```

This gives me:

```
Backup Server dbserver/db1 is DOWN, reason: Socket error, info: "Connection reset by peer", check duration: 5ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Server dbserver/db2 is DOWN, reason: Socket error, info: "Connection reset by peer", check duration: 3ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

That looked to me like a network issue but, when testing manually, I can `telnet 1.2.3.2 3306` from the new haproxy server and get `5.5.60-MariaDBM}O>)Q=|z▒@/jHiZdgZm6amysql_native_password`, so it would seem the database server is accepting connections from the new server. I can also `telnet 1.2.3.2 9200` from the new server and get the same `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response as from the old, so that also seems to be connecting. Why might haproxy not be able to do the same?